# Create asset catalogue programmatically in swift

Tags: ios, swift

Am fairly new to swift (in fact who isn't, but am new to iOS development too) and currently working on an app which involves good number of images. I could categorise the images and add it in asset catalogues for the initial app. However, there would be some options for the user to download the images also. In such case, i would like to add the images to an asset or create a new asset catalogue programmatically. I am not sure whether its a good idea or is there any other better idea to store the images? Googled for some suggestions , but I couldn't get any.. Any help / suggestions would be much appreciated..

Comment: I doubt it, Asset Catalogues are a compile time tool, and I doubt you can do anything using them at run time on the device.

Comment: thanks.. so, there is no option to save the downloading images. I could create a new folder every time though for newly created images.. gotcha..

Comment: Just don't try and save them in your app bundle.